# How do I render a component inside another dynamically loaded component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a custom Grid component, in which I want to render/pass other components. I created a Grid component and I'm dynamically loading it in my `dashboard.component.ts`.

Here is my Grid's template.

```
<div nz-row *ngFor="let row of grid; index as i;">
    <div nz-col *ngFor="let col of row; index as j;">
      <div>
        <ng-template name="{{i}}{{j}}"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'ng-template[name]'
})
export class CustomGridDirective {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

My `custom-grid.component.ts`,

```
export class CustomGridComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() grid: any;
  @ViewChildren(CustomGridDirective) gridContainer: QueryList<CustomGridDirective>;
  
  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

`Dashboard.component.ts`, where I'm dynamically loading my Grid component.

```
async customGrid(){
  const {CustomGridComponent} = await import('../custom-grid/custom-grid.component');
  const customGridFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CustomGridComponent);
  let {instance} = this.anchor1.createComponent(customGridFactory, null, this.injector);
  instance.grid = [
    ['1', '2', '3']
  ]
  return instance
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.customGrid().then( component => console.log(component.gridContainer));
}
```

Now, I'm unable to access `component.gridContainer` or even `component.grid`. Both return, `undefined`.

Say I have a `dashboard-widget-1.component`, how do I dynamically render it inside the custom-grid component? I was trying to approach the ViewChildren's query list and try to render the component inside.

But I get `component.gridContainer` and `component.grid`, both, as undefined. How can I dynamically render components, such as `dashboard-widget-1.component` and `dashboard-widget-2.component` in my Grid Component (which I have dynamically loaded)?

I'm stuck since days, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to prepare stackblitz?

Comment: Hello Yuri, here's my StackBlitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4akuyg. I want to render/insert a template inside either 00, 01, 02 etc that is shown in the screen. Thank you, please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `undefined` because there wasn't any change detection cycle executed on that component yet.

```
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

const widgetFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CustomWidgetComponent);
instance.galleryContainer.forEach(target => {
  target.viewContainerRef.createComponent(widgetFactory, null, this.injector)
});
```

Also if you want to lazy load component then make sure imported file contains NgModule which describes all dependant declarations:

**custom-grid.components.ts**

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class CustomGridComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
... 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [CustomGridComponent, CustomGridDirective],
})
export class CustomGridModule { }
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sn7aar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-grid%2Fcustom-grid.component.ts)**